# Perl: print back to beginning of line

Tags: perl, command-line

Okay, so what I'm trying to do is print out a percentage complete to my command line, now, I would like this to simply 'update' the number shown on the screen. So somehow go back to the beginning of the line and change it.

For example the windows relog.exe command-line utility (which can convert a .blg file to a .csv file) does this. If you run it, it will display a percentage complete.

Now this is probably written in C++.
I don't know if this is possible in perl as well ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use "\r" or "\015" octal (aka "Return caret" aka "[Carriage Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)" character originating from typewriter days :)

```
> perl5.8 -e 'print "11111\r222\r3\n";'
32211
> perl5.8 -e 'print "11111\015222\0153\n";'  
32211
```

Just don't forget to print at least as many characters as the longest string already printed to overwrite any old characters (as you can see in example above, the failure to do so will keep old characters).

Another thing to be aware of is, as Michael pointed in the commment, the autoflush needs to be turned on while these printings happen, so that the output doesn't wait for newline character at the very end of the processing.

**UPDATE:** Please note that 013 octal character recommended in another answer is actually a Vertical Tab:

```
> perl5.8 -e 'print "11111\013222\0133\n";'    
11111
     222
        3
```

Comment: For a full list of special characters you can print, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: You also need to turn on autoflushing (`$| = 1`) as by default output is buffered until a newline is seen. (Or until the buffer is full, but that won't happen for a progress meter.)

Comment: @Michael - my original answer included autoflushing, I removed it to keep the line lengths down as it was not strictly speaking related to the meat of the question... Adding as a note

Comment: @DVK FWIW that other answer didn't suggest octal 13, it suggested *decimal* 13, which is in fact `\r` (`\x0d`).

Comment: And also note that the vertical tab isn't something that's recognized in every shell.  :)

Comment: Thanks man, that was what I was looking for, and indeed, also needed autoflushing !

Comment: @DVK: I feel frustrated to get a -1 when you cannot figure there's no difference between 015 (octal) and 13 (decimal).

Comment: @Didier - +1-ed you to assuage your frustration... though to be hoinest your answer didn't really deserve a +1 independent of whether I personally read it carefully enough or not. No explanation of why 13, no attempt to test if it works.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you'd like to do, `pv` might solve your problem. It can wrap any script that takes a file as input, and add a progress bar.

For example

```
pv data.gz | gunzip -c | ./complicated-perl-script-that-reads-stdin
```

`pv` is packaged for RedHat/CentOS and Ubuntu at least. More information: http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

Otherwise I'd use CPAN, e.g. [Term::ProgressBar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ProgressBar).

Comment: @rjh - I have a feeling he is on Windows, so he may need a DOS/Windows pv port

Comment: +1 for CPAN module - I'm not sure how usedful it's to OP but it's very educational to know about

Answer (score 2):

You can also use \b to move back one character:

```
local $| = 1; #flush immediately
print "Doing it - 10%";
sleep(1);
print "\b\b\b";
print "20%";
print "\n", "Done", "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, the trick is to print char #13. Maybe it can work in Perl.

```
for (int pc = 0 ; pc <= 100 ; ++pc)
    printf("Percentage: %02d %%  %c", pc, 13);
printf("\n");
```