# Can java do a timer on command line by overwriting the time on the same line?

Tags: java, time

HI I am a new java programmer (very new).

What I want to do/test is (not sure if its recommendable or doable?), we know that

```
System.out.println("Message");
```

will output the "Message" in command prompt. Is it possible to display the current time, without having to repeatly use the system.out.println()?

Name, like instead of displaying:

```
10:00:01
10:00:02
10:00:03
```

I wand to have liek this:
    10:00:0X where X will continue counting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you emit a `\r` (carriage-return) instead of a `\n` (line-end), in most terminals, the cursor will go back to the start of the *same* line, so you can "overwrite" the line next time. `println` automatically adds a `\n`, but you can use `System.out.print` (without the `ln` part;-) to avoid that (you may also have to call method `flush` to make sure everything you printed was actually output, as opposed to being held in a memory buffer).

Comment: so, something liek this: system.out.print("message"); flush();? Sorry, I am still a noob java programmer

Comment: What's up with this week and \r questions? :)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774596/perl-print-back-to-beginning-of-line/2774660#2774660

Comment: BTW, in the interest of completeness, "\r" is referred to as "Carriage Return" character (originating from typewriter days when you "returned the carriage" to the beginning of the line :)

Comment: @DVK: Means, there are more and more new programmers nowadays? Most new programmers starts their programming life by using simple "print" function (thats how I learn my first programming language) lol

Comment: @javaLearner.java - but carriage return is somewhat of a specialized thing - and I don't recall a single question about it in about a year I was on SO; and this week I saw two... Just to be clear, my comment was amazement at the coincidence, not objection to your question :)