# Perl. How can I make output disappear after several seconds?

Tags: perl, shell, prompt

I'm prompting a user for a correct answer for example:

```
/> 13 + 7 ?
```

is it any way of making this output disappear after 2 seconds for example ?

..thanks' for any suggestions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774596/perl-print-back-to-beginning-of-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select` on `STDIN` to see whether there is any input within 2 seconds. If not, overwrite the output with a carriage return (`\r`) or multiple backspaces (`\b`).

Proof of concept:

```
$| = 1;                  # needed because print calls don't always use a newline
$i = int(rand() * 10);
$j = int(rand() * 10);
$k = $i + $j;

print "What is $i + $j ? ";

$rin = '';
vec($rin, fileno(STDIN), 1) = 1;
$n = select $rout=$rin, undef, undef, 2.0;

if ($n) {
    $answer = <STDIN>;
    if ($answer == $k) {
        print "You are right.\n";
    } else {
        print "You are wrong. $i + $j is $k\n";
    }
} else {
    print "\b \b" x 15;
    print "\n\n";
    print "Time's up!\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

When you are ready for a more advanced solution, you could probably check out `Term::ReadKey` (so you don't have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you type in your answer) or something like `Curses` to exercise more control over writing to arbitrary spots on your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for a few things combined, I think:

1) how do you erase a line

2) how do you wait for input for a while and then give up on waiting (ie, a timer)

The following code will do what you want (there are other ways of accomplishing both of the above, but the below shows one way for each of the above tasks):

```
use strict; use warnings;
use IO::Select;

my $stdin = IO::Select->new();
$stdin->add(\*STDIN);

# always flush
$| = 1;

my $question = "/> 7 + 3 ? ";

print $question;
if ($stdin->can_read(2)) {
    print "you entered: " . <STDIN>;
} else {
    print "\010" x length($question);
    print " " x length($question);
    print "too late\n";
}
```